# Project build error: Unknown packaging: kjar

Tags: jbpm

Using Jbpm 6.4.0 full installer from here: http://www.jbpm.org/download/download.html

1. start demo: ant start.demo
2. using eclipse, create a new jBPM project from jBPM playground 6.3 and select translations project

[image]

3. add maven nature to the project
4. try to install/compile you can see following error on problems tab:

[image]

> Project build error: Unknown packaging: kjar

**Question is**: what is kjar packaging ? How is project working in a demo enviroment ?

My Eclipse is:

[image]

Edit:

I've found definition on what is a [kjar](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.4.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html/ch14.html#d0e14589), in particular this part on official documentation:

> Version 6, on the other hand moves away from proprietary packages in
> favor of, well known and mature, Apache Maven based packaging - known
> as knowledge archives - kjar. Processes, rules etc (aka business
> assets) are now part of a simple jar file built and managed by Maven.
> Along the business assets, java classes and other file types are
> stored in the jar file too. Moreover, as any other maven artifact,
> kjar can have defined dependencies on other artifacts including other
> kjars. What makes the kjar special when compared with regular jars is
> a single descriptor file kept inside META-INF directory of the kjar -
> kmodule.xml. That descriptor allows to define:
>
> - knowledge bases and their properties
> - knowledge sessions and their properties
> - work item handlers
> - event listeners
>
> By default, this descriptor is empty (just kmodule root element) and
> is considered as marker file. Whenever a runtime component (such as
> jbpm console) is about to process kjar it looks up kmodule.xml to
> build its runtime representation. In addition to kmodule.xml a
> deployment descriptor (that provides fine graind control over
> deployment) is available (since 6.1).

After reading this it's not clear how to build these kjar and why official online example for jbpm include kjar as packaging value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿did you test if commenting the line works?
just comment the line 8:
change this:

```
<packaging>kjar</packaging>
```

into this:

```
<!-- <packaging>kjar</packaging> -->
```

Im not sure, but I think that there is a version mismatch between the code and the documentation. I think the default packaging is jar, so removing line 8 from the configuration will work.

Comment: I've tried, but my question is more on understand what kjar is and why a demo environment is not working

Comment: This is not the answer; its working is by coincidence.  See below.

Answer (score 1):

This is compatible with Project Modeling environment previously called KIE Workbench and now Business Central. In that setup kie-maven-plugin is setup correctly and it will work.

In most cases you do not need kjar and build tags in maven.

Answer (score 1):

Business Central, as a web front end to JBPM, handles packaging and deployment.  However, in environments where Business Central is not or cannot be used the KJar packaging is used for maven builds (e.g., building from the command line or an IDE like Eclipse.)

Maven uses the kie-maven-plugin to organize, compile and package resources. However, there seems to be some state-related problems with kie-maven-plugin because my projects create kjrar's and jar's unreliably; the documented way to create kjar's is with the kie-maven-plugin:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
                <artifactId>kie-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jbpm.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
...
            <plugin>
```

what is needed in the plugin configuration depends upon the JBPM resources you are using.